# datetime insertion problem in drupal

Tags: php, mysql, drupal-6

```
$date_time = date("y-m-d h:i:s", time());

db_query("INSERT INTO {category}(category_name, sort_order, date, category_image)
VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')", $form['name']['#post'], $form['name']['#post'], $date_time, $form['name']['#post']);
```

here current date in not inserted... what should i use instead of %s ?  or how can i solve this problem. Want a easy reply please.

Thanks.

Comment: check the "date" field in mysql and see what values does it accept , allso check for any query errors you might recive . it's not that hard to debug .

Answer (score 1):

Use integer type for the datetime field.
And try this :

```
$current_time = time();

db_query("INSERT INTO {category}(category_name, sort_order, date, category_image)
VALUES ('%s', '%s', %d, '%s')", $form['name']['#post'], $form['name']['#post'], $current_time, $form['name']['#post']);
```

Answer (score 0):

try `$date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());`

the `h` is 01-12 instead of `H` - 00 to 23

and back-tick the reserved keywords like

```
(category_name, sort_order, `date`, category_image)
```

**PS:** please don't use reserved keywords as column, is so troublesome

Comment: this also shows same results...but i have solved this problem.   $date_time = date("y-m-d h:i:s", time());
db_query("INSERT INTO {category}(category_name, sort_order, date, category_image)VALUES ('%s', '%s', '$date_time', '%s')", $form['name']['#post'], $form['name']['#post'], $form['name']['#post']);  Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

What type is the data for the 'date' column in your table?
%s expects and only inserts string values - the php date function returns a string so you probably have a data type mismatch there. try adding this line:

```
$date_time=strtotime($date_time);
```

and then inserting it to your database. This should only work if the data type of the column is date or datetime.

Comment: Your comment on the ajreal's answer suggests that you inserted the date in the database as a string - this could be a problem if you intend to sort db entries by date or manipulate them date-wise.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question but just some advice. In a Drupal module you should never use "INSERT" when writing to the database, instead use drupal_write_record ( http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_write_record/6).